# Change column type from choice to lookup without data loss

Tags: 2010, feature-upgrade

I have a feature which contains lists definitions, content types and site columns.
There is one site column of choice type with 10 options.
I need to change type from choice to lookup and get that options from a list containing the same items as options in old column. Enabling users to add more options just by adding items to the list.
There is already some data on production so i should fill new lookup column according to old options from choice type.
Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way.

I would use feature upgrading code to create a new list with the desired valaues. Then I would add the lookup column to the list and views. Then iterate through all the list items which have a value in the choice field and set the appropriate lookup value. When complete, delete the choice column from the list and views.

Answer (score 0):

Export existing data into an Excel File.

Now using feature etc. change column type to Lookup.

Now put List in Data Sheet Edit Mode. Copy paste from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1) add a new field with the lookup relationship
2) link to the table and the related table
3) create a query to update values in the first table with the values in the related where choice value = lookup value.